# vba displaying certain list as dropdown depending on result

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make it so that a dropdown list is created, the list becoming a dropdown depends on the result of an `IF` statement. Each list is called "MyList" followed by a number (MyList2, MyList9 etc.) I am using he following code to determine which list should be used and to create the dropdown:

```
For i = 3 To 31
        If customer = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("lists1").Range("B" & i).Value Then
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Off-Site_Expendicture").Range("CusLoc").Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList & i, ",")
            End With
        End If
Next i
```

I believe that this doesn't work due to the fact you can't use (MyList & i) I have tried all I can think to get it work but can't find a way. Everything works fine except the 'with' statement.

Comment: Are the lists named ranges?

Comment: If yes, try `("MyList" & i, ",")` (adding quotes around `MyList`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad i get a type mismatch when doing this, same as before

Comment: I'm assuming that the "named lists" are actually named ranges, assuming that's the case, try `Formula1:="=MyList" & i`